# Path-based routing without ending slash Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, gateway

I'm currently working on Azure Application Gateway to redirect request to 2 WebApi using Path-based rule as below:

```
"/foo/*" -> FooApi
"/bar/*" -> BarApi
```

And a default backend api that does nothing for now.

When I request to `http://mygateway.azure.com/foo/`, it works fine.
But if I missed an ending slash, so with the URL `http://mygateway.azure.com/foo`, it returns **500 URL Rewrite Module Error**.

Current **ApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings** I set **-Path** to **"/"**.

I tried to add few more routes to the rule liked `"/foo"`, `"/foo/"`, but it doesn't work.

Any advises, please?

Comment: Have you added any health probes to the HttpSettings? They can be helpful to see if your routing to the Backend Pools is set up right. Also, have you tried setting the `ApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings` **-Path** to "/*"?

Comment: This could possibly be related to the trailing-slash redirect problem stated in this [issue-link](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/458). 
You can try adding an explicit rule to handle paths without trailing slash (/) to see if that helps.